# How does linq Expression<TDelegate> assignment work on a language syntax level

Tags: c#, linq, delegates, moq, linq-expressions

TLDR: How does this compile?

```
class A{};
Expression<Func<A, int>> e = x => 24; // I don't understant what makes this compile
                                      // and what happens at this assignment
```

What is the minimum `class E` to be able to compile `E e = x => 24;`

---

Some investigation

```
class E {};

E e = x => 24;
```

Visual Studio error is "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'E' because it is not a delegate type" which is confusing because as far as I know a delegate is declared like this:

```
int delegate MyHandle();
```

and I didn't find any way of making a `class` a delegate.

Furthermore I have looked at the metadata of `Expression -> LambdaExpression -> Expression<TDelegate>` and wasn't able to identify what syntax/declaration makes `Expression<TDelegate>` act like a delegate.

Even more I have tried to create my own `class E` to mimic `Expression<TDelegate>` and I wasn't even able to compile the class

```
// basically a copy-paste of the metadata of `Expression<TDelegate>`
public sealed class E<TDelegate> : LambdaExpression
{

    public TDelegate Compile() => default(TDelegate);
    public TDelegate Compile(DebugInfoGenerator debugInfoGenerator) => default(TDelegate);
    public TDelegate Compile(bool preferInterpretation) => default(TDelegate);
    public Expression Update(Expression body, IEnumerable<ParameterExpression> parameters)
        => default(Expression);
    protected override Expression Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor) => null;
}
```

getting the error "'LambdaExpression' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments"

---

Context (can be skipped):

I am getting started with Moq and because I just cannot take things for granted I am trying to understand how it works / how it is implemented. So this the first part of a series of inquiries about that.

I am now specifically trying to understand

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Foo() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public virtual int Bar() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

var a = new Mock<A>();

a.Setup(x => x.Foo()).Returns(24); // ??
Console.WriteLine(a.Object.Foo());
```

I am trying to understand how the information "the method Foo" is passed to `a`
by passing that lambda? As far as I know a lambda is just a callable object, but somehow magically `a` knows the actual body of the lambda, i.e. will throw if you pass `x => 24` or `x => x.Foo() + x.Bar()` but will accept `x => x.Foo()`

And I see that `Setup` parameter is of type `Expression<Func<A, int>>` hence my current question.

Comment: To be precise, the error _Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'E' because it is not a delegate type_ could be expanded to _Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'E' because it is neither a delegate type nor a generic type constructed  from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<TDelegate>'_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# specification gives special treatment to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<D>`; you cannot get the same treatment for your own type.

> Expression trees permit lambda expressions to be represented as data structures instead of executable code. Expression trees are values of expression tree types of the form `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<D>`, where `D` is any delegate type.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#expression-tree-types

Answer (score 0):

This is a Lambda expression:

```
x => 24
```

According to [MSDN Lambda expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) a lambda expression can be used to create a *delegate* or an *expression tree type*.

A `Func<T, int>` is a delegate function that takes a T as input and returns an int as output. If you assign the lambda expression above to this Func, then the compiler assumes that the `x` in the lambda expression is the input of the Func, and the part after the `=>` is the output of the Func:

```
Func<string, int> func = x => x.Length;
```

Here x is expected to be a string, the part after the `=>` may use, but is not obliged to use, this x to produce the output which has to be an int.

```
Func<int, int> func = x => x = -x;
```

Here x is expected to be an int. The return of the function is -x which is also an int.

`Expression` is the base class of all kinds of expressions. Expressions represent an operation that return a value. The most basic expressions are constants, they represent just a constant value, like `24`. Other expressions might be additions, which take as input two expressions and have one output value. Other expressions are multiplication, negation, etc, which return a "number", or boolean expressions like AND OR NOR etc which return a Boolean.

A special kind of expression (so a derived class) is a `LambdaExpression`. A `LambdaExpression` usually represents a function-like object: it has zero or more input parameters and one output parameter. You assign a value to a `LambdaExpression` using a lambda expression (note the space in lambda expression!):

```
Expression<Func<string, int>> myExpression = x => x.Length;
```

I wrote earlier what the lambda expression `x => x.Length` does. the statement above creates an object of type [`System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<TDelegate>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression-1?view=netframework-4.7.2), which is of type [LambdaExpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2), hence you can assign it to an `Expression<Func<string, int>>`.

Your question:

> What is the minimum class E to be able to compile `E e = x => 24`?

Your class E will need a constructor (or assignment operator) that accepts a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<MyClass, int>` as parameter. If you don't use the `x` from your lambda expression `MyClass` can be `object`

Of course it is also accepted if the constructor takes any of the base classes, like `Expression`. However, if you do so you won't be able to used any of the `Expression<Func<MyClass, int>` functionality.

**About your Mock code**

Apparently you have a class A with two functions Foo and Bar, and you want to instantiate a Mock object to mock the functionality of A.

```
var myAmock = new Mock<A>();
myAmock.Setup(x => x.Foo()).Returns(24);
```

This says, that `myAmock` is an object that should mock behaviour of class `A`. Whenever someone calls the `Foo` function it should return a value of 24.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know what a lambda is. I know what an expression tree is. I know what the mock does. What I didn't know was that lambdas are treated as data (an expression tree) when assigned to an `Expression` which Ben Voigt explained.